# Checking if a value exists in a list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary with a list of dictionaries. How do I do a lookup to check if a certain name exists in key 'firstname'?

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
  
   vars:
     Persons:
       - firstname: Bob
       - firstname: Sarah

     name: Sarah

   tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ name in Persons }}" - ????
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on another post -

```
- debug: msg="{{ name in Persons | map(attribute='firstname') | list }}"
```